# jQuery Deconstruction | Calling mechanism for $.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Where is ajax defined in the source and how it is bound to the jQuery object?

I ran a search for it and found it on 5993 inside this thing called:

```
jQuery.extend({
```

where fn is an alias for prototype.

How does Jquery know were to find ajax() when you call it.  More generally how does extend work?

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

Comment: Open the uncompressed jQuery source and search for `"ajax:"`. It's the first match.Notice that this method is added via `jQuery.extend()`, not `jQuery.fn.extend()`. This is because it's a static method, defined on the `jQuery` object itself, rather than a jQuery method.

Comment: A great place to view jQuery internals is at this website: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.ajax. You just search for the function you want, and it displays it. It can even pull the latest version of jQuery from github.

Comment: So `$.` the dot specifies a method is to be used....and ajax() has been copied to the prototype at some point...it is a prototyped method on the jQuery object.

Comment: `jQuery.extend = jQuery.fn.extend`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `extend` method copies properties from one object to another.  With just one argument, it copies properties to `this`, so in this case it's copying the properties to the `fn` object itself.

*edit* in my copy of the 1.7.1 code, the "ajax" method actually is copied in by `jQuery.extend()`, not `jQuery.fn.extend()`.  It's the same function; `extend` is bound to both the jQuery object and to the "fn" object (the internal constructor function).  When it's called as `jQuery.extend({ ... })` therefore, the properties are copied to the jQuery object (function) itself.

Comment: this relates to the previous question I asked but I'm not so sure about it...I think `this` might actually point to the containing object of the function...and not the function object ( or JQuery object have you) itself...that probably does not make sense...I'm going to perform an experiment and figure this out once and for all.

Comment: `return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );`...I think returns something that points to `jQuery` instantiated.

Comment: they are basically calling new on a prototype...I don't think this sort of thing is covered in textbooks.